# INNER JOIN after LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two queries that work great. And the latter is run once for each row of the former. I would like to combine them if possible for performance. The latter returns zero or one rows.

The issue is that both queries use INNER JOINs I need to glue them with a LEFT JOIN. Is this legal, and is it well defined what will happen if an INNER JOIN is used "after" a LEFT JOIN. Lastly, will such a machination have any performance penalties over the existing approach which is "fast"?

For reference, and I'm sorry if this is TMI, here is my first query:

```
SELECT
  pmt_attempts.user_id,
  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(attempt_time_end, '%Y') + 2, DATE_FORMAT(attempt_time_end, '-%m-%d')) as date_expired,
  course_sku,
  um_fn.meta_value AS 'shipping_first_name',
  um_ln.meta_value AS 'shipping_last_name',
  um_cr.meta_value AS 'credentials',
  pmt_orders.promocode_used,
  pmt_promocodes.sales_channel
FROM
  pmt_attempts
INNER JOIN
  pmt_courses 
    ON pmt_attempts.course_id = pmt_courses.course_id
INNER JOIN
  pmt_orders 
    ON pmt_orders.order_id = pmt_attempts.order_id
INNER JOIN
  wp_usermeta um_fn 
    ON pmt_orders.user_id = um_fn.user_id
    AND um_fn.meta_key = 'shipping_first_name'
INNER JOIN
  wp_usermeta um_ln 
    ON pmt_orders.user_id = um_ln.user_id
    AND um_ln.meta_key = 'shipping_last_name'
LEFT JOIN
  wp_usermeta um_cr 
    ON pmt_orders.user_id = um_cr.user_id
    AND um_cr.meta_key = 'credentials'
INNER JOIN
  pmt_order_course 
    ON fk_order_id = pmt_attempts.order_id
    AND fk_course_id = pmt_attempts.course_id
LEFT JOIN
  pmt_promocodes 
    ON pmt_orders.promocode_used = pmt_promocodes.promocode_text
WHERE
  attempt_time_end >= '2014-01-01' AND <--- CONFIGURABLE REPORT PARAM
  attempt_time_end < '2014-02-01' AND <--- CONFIGURABLE REPORT PARAM
  attempt_complete = 'Y' AND
  (unenroll_date IS NULL OR unenroll_date = '0000-00-00') AND
  1
ORDER BY
  attempt_time_end
;
```

and here is the second query:

```
SELECT
  course_sku,
  pmt_orders.order_date,
  attempt_time_end,
  pmt_order_course.unenroll_date
FROM
  pmt_order_course
INNER JOIN
  pmt_orders ON 
    pmt_orders.order_id = pmt_order_course.fk_order_id
INNER JOIN
  pmt_courses ON 
    pmt_courses.course_id = pmt_order_course.fk_course_id
LEFT JOIN
  pmt_attempts ON 
    pmt_attempts.course_id = pmt_courses.course_id AND
    pmt_attempts.order_id = pmt_orders.order_id AND 
    pmt_attempts.attempt_complete = 'Y'
WHERE
  pmt_orders.user_id = 928 AND <--- FROM FIRST QUERY ROW
  course_sku LIKE 'BL%' AND <--- FIRST TWO LETTERS OF FIRST QUERY ROW + %
  pmt_orders.order_date > '2012-12-14' <--- FROM FIRST QUERY ROW
ORDER BY
  pmt_orders.order_date
LIMIT
  1
;
```

The purpose of this query is to find, for each order, whether the customer "renewed" and bought another of the same, or similar, product at a later time.

Comment: What do you mean by "Combine" them. There are many ways to combine two queries (UNION, JOINing the results sets, incorporating the logic of one into the other)? What is the relationship between the two? In both of these you have a LEFT JOIN following a bunch of INNER's, so why the worry?

Comment: The latter is run once for each row of the former. I would like to do the whole thing in one shebang. The relationship is annotated inline in the code of the latter.

Comment: to be clear, are you trying to return both the result set as well as the extra zero or one row from the query, or are you trying to return ONLY the zero or one row from the second query?  As far as left joining after an inner join, yes this is absolutely legal, but I think we're still not entirely clear of your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of with wloud be great here, but if You are in MySQL [FROM subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html) is what You need.

Given that this long firest query if **Q1**, and that course_sku column is from pmt_orders table, we can write:

```
SELECT
  course_sku,
  pmt_orders.order_date,
  attempt_time_end,
  pmt_order_course.unenroll_date
FROM
    (Q1 here) q1
INNER JOIN pmt_order_course ON (pmt_orders.user_id = q1.user_id AND pmt_orders.course_sku LIKE CONCAT(q1.course_sku,'%') AND pmt_orders.order_date > q1.date_expired)
INNER JOIN pmt_orders ON (pmt_orders.order_id = pmt_order_course.fk_order_id)
INNER JOIN pmt_courses ON (pmt_courses.course_id = pmt_order_course.fk_course_id)
LEFT JOIN pmt_attempts ON (pmt_attempts.course_id = pmt_courses.course_id AND pmt_attempts.order_id = pmt_orders.order_id AND pmt_attempts.attempt_complete = 'Y')
WHERE 1 = 1      
ORDER BY
  pmt_orders.order_date
LIMIT
  1
;
```